# MacOS Mojave stopped showing certain icons in the menu bar

Tags: time-machine, mojave, menu-bar

Recently I started up my computer (MBP 2015) and I realized all of the system icons were missing. The time, wifi, keyboard, etc were are missing. However all of the icons that come from programs I have installed still appear. The only system icon that does appear is spotlight. Every once in a while I will see a quick flash and all of the icons will shift left. I have reset my NVRAM, and tried to boot into safe mode but it didn't seem to work. I also tried to backup my computer to wipe it, but I had an unrelated issue with time machine where it said the format of my drive was incorrect, even though I have backed up to the same device before.

[image]

Comment: Try reinstalling the OS from Recovery. This should refresh the OS whilst leaving data/settings/apps etc alone. (Personally, I've developed a deep distrust of Time Machine in recent years - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/392734/85275 for a cautionary tale)

Comment: Can you recommend a better tool to backup data with?

Comment: I use Backblaze - but it doesn't have Time Machine's (theoretical) instant recovery/migration.