# Can a "test restoration" of macOS from time machine be done?

Tags: time-machine, ssd, restore

I maintain regular backups of my systems: three (3) Macbook Pros, vintage 2011, 2016 & 2019. I use Time Machine for backups now, and I have so far been fortunate enough to not need to use a backup to restore a system. However, I feel that my good luck may work against me if and when I do need to restore a system.

Is there some method or process by which I could make a *"test restoration"* of a Time Machine backup to gain some practice or familiarity ***without*** putting my system at risk? For example, perhaps I could restore the backup to an external SSD, and then boot from that external drive?

Comment: I've had them not work more times than they have, so I'd definitely test it. I've always had Mac Pros, so I can jut put another internal drive in, so it's not a direct comparison. I'd just go for it & see if Recovery will let you just do this straight to an external. Personally, I also always keep a clone that's not too old, & also Backblaze, so I've got belt & braces.

Comment: See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/392734/migration-assistant-fail and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/421062/the-volume-is-the-wrong-format-for-a-backup-why for variations on a theme of *"It no werky!"*

Comment: @Tetsujin: A "clone"... as in CCC?

Comment: @Tetsujin: re yr 1st comment: Pls correct me if wrong, but: **1.** clone=disk image ?, **2.** Backblaze=file backup only?

Comment: Yes to both. Clone is a full bootable copy of the drive, CCC. BB is files only, in case the house burns down;)